# BSc, MSc, PhD vs. B.Sc., M.Sc., Ph.D

Tags: american-english, british-english, abbreviations

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/) prefers Ph.D. over PhD in US English. But at the same time, there is no B.Sc. and no M.Sc. entry in OED, which leads me into thinking that there is a mismatch: Ph.D. is typically written with periods, but MSc and BSc without in the US English. Am I right? Which forms are most widespread in the US? And in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, [the Associated Press style](https://www.bkacontent.com/rules-capitalizing-academic-degrees-ap-style/) uses periods:  *B.S., M.S., Ph.D., M.D.*, etc.  However, other sources may use a different style, (e.g. PhD).

*B.Sc.* and *M.Sc*. are not the usual degree abbreviations in the US.  Instead use *B.S.* and *M.S.*

Comment: To complete the answer, add that in British usage, no periods: PhD, MSc MA BSc BA and so on